# How to find and backup your local GIT repository to be able to restore it later?

Tags: git, backup

Where is my local GIT repository and can I back it up and restore it if need be to the same computer or another computer later?

**Update:**
Sorry, to be more clear, my Mac popped up a message that says, "You haven't backed up in 12 days" and I thought, "the only thing that has changed on my computer since then is the code in my project. I wonder if I can backup my local git repository to a USB drive and if anything happens I can restore it later if I need to, to another computer. Also, I haven't committed all of my changes."

Comment: Um, it's not clear what you're asking. Shouldn't you know where your own git repository is? It's where you ran `git init`. But generally it's not worth backing up - you'd normally just make sure you're pushing to somewhere that's already being backed up.

Comment: I don't want to push to remote yet, but want to make sure I have an up to date backup available. Also, I updated the question.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Consider working in a branch, then you can push to your remote whenever you like. [This is a good policy in general](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow).

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't use command line tools. I use GitHub's UI, and SourceTree and GitHub.com (which has a button to clone in desktop). The repository is the same root directory as the files correct?

Comment: I strongly urge you to get at least reasonably comfortable with the command line - and as Schwern says, push to a branch. I suspect the message has nothing to do with Git though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git's "repository" is stored in the hidden `.git` folder in your project. You can back it up, restore it, copy it, etc.

To backup all of your files and the repository backup the parent folder of the .git directory.

```
/myProject
  /.git
  /myproject.txt
```

Backing up `/myProject` will backup the repository and all of your files, *committed* changes and *uncommitted* changes.

Comment: Note that backing up the `.git` folder will *not* include uncommitted changes. It will also be difficult to extract staged changes, so it's best to make sure everything is committed or stashed (which is also committed).

Comment: So if I backup the directory with the .git folder (the parent folder of the .git directory) that would include all my files and my local git repo?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts yup, it should.

Answer (score 1):

Your local git repository is a great thing to backup because it's a full git repository. You can use it always to restore your git respository, for other people, too!

Just copy the `.git`-directory to another place. But be aware: it could be big!

Comment: Even with very old, very large projects `.git` is usually no more than twice the size of the checkout.

Comment: I've noticed that in cases where you have binary files it can get pretty large. I had some psd's that I modified and the directory was pretty big. i'm not 100% sure tho.